# JUnit4 - Parallel launch of Test Suites

Tags: java, selenium, junit, junit4, test-suite

I have two TestSuite classes (`TestSuiteOne` and `TestSuiteTwo`)

They look so:

```
import org.junit.runners.Suite;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(Suite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses({TestClass1.class, TestClass2.class})
public class TestSuiteOne {
  //nothing
}
```

How can I run them in parallel?
One I run so `$mvn class test -Dtest=TestSuiteOne`

But how do I run them at the same time?

Comment: maven has parallel attribute in surefire plugin which will you to run tests in parallel

Comment: Yes, in maven you can run tests in parallel. With classes, it works for me. With suites - no

Comment: Or I just do not know how to do it correctly

Answer (score 0):

So here's hack! You create Suites via TestNG i.e mention the classes in TestNG.xml and set the junit option as true in that xml. Next You configure maven to run testng test suites in parallel as mentioned here: [maven-parallel-suites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45010589/how-to-run-parallel-suites-in-maven-and-testng)

Comment: Maybe in this case it's better to switch to TestNG?

Comment: At any given day switching to TestNG is the preferred and recommended way. But I thought you had stringent requirement to stick to JUnit hence the above hacky way.